# How to draw SVG icon using html and css?

Tags: html, css, icons

is this possible to draw such kind of icons, i have tried so far but i am unable to make such kind of icon using html and css.

I am trying following code

```
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
<path d="M16 32c8.837 0 16-7.160 16-16s-7.163-16-16-16-16 7.163-16 16 7.163 16 16 16zM16 3c7.18 0 13 5.82 13 13s-5.82 13-13 13-13-5.82-13-13 5.82-13 13-13zM8 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM20 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM22.003 19.602l2.573 1.544c-1.749 2.908-4.935 4.855-8.576 4.855s-6.827-1.946-8.576-4.855l2.573-1.544c1.224 2.036 3.454 3.398 6.003 3.398s4.779-1.362 6.003-3.398z"></path>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: You'd need multiple paths/svg sub-elements etc to make that icon...not one.

Comment: @Paulie_D Actually i am unable to draw due to lack of knowledge

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the existing paths into separate ones...the delimiter in the `path` code is the `M`

```
<path class="left-eye" 
 d="M8 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM20 10c0-1.105 
 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM22.003 19.602l2.573 1.544c-1.749 2.908-4.935 
 4.855-8.576 4.855s-6.827-1.946-8.576-4.855l2.573-1.544c1.224 2.036 3.454 
 3.398 6.003 3.398s4.779-1.362 6.003-3.398z"></path>
```

See these examples:

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.green {
  fill: green;
}

.red {
  fill: red;
}

.left-eye {
  fill: blue;
}

.right-eye {
  fill: pink;
}

.smile {
  fill: orange;
}

.features {
  fill: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox=" 0 0 32 32">
  <path class="green "d="M16 32c8.837 0 16-7.160 16-16s-7.163-16-16-16-16 7.163-16 16 7.163 16 16 16z"></path>
  <path class="red "d="M16 3c7.18 0 13 5.82 13 13s-5.82 13-13 13-13-5.82-13-13 5.82-13 13-13zM8 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM20 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM22.003 19.602l2.573 1.544c-1.749 2.908-4.935 4.855-8.576 4.855s-6.827-1.946-8.576-4.855l2.573-1.544c1.224 2.036 3.454 3.398 6.003 3.398s4.779-1.362 6.003-3.398z"></path>
    <path class="left-eye" d="M8 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM20 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM22.003 19.602l2.573 1.544c-1.749 2.908-4.935 4.855-8.576 4.855s-6.827-1.946-8.576-4.855l2.573-1.544c1.224 2.036 3.454 3.398 6.003 3.398s4.779-1.362 6.003-3.398z"></path>
      <path class="right-eye" d="M20 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM22.003 19.602l2.573 1.544c-1.749 2.908-4.935 4.855-8.576 4.855s-6.827-1.946-8.576-4.855l2.573-1.544c1.224 2.036 3.454 3.398 6.003 3.398s4.779-1.362 6.003-3.398z"></path>
        <path class="smile" d="M22.003 19.602l2.573 1.544c-1.749 2.908-4.935 4.855-8.576 4.855s-6.827-1.946-8.576-4.855l2.573-1.544c1.224 2.036 3.454 3.398 6.003 3.398s4.779-1.362 6.003-3.398z"></path>
</svg>

<svg viewbox=" 0 0 32 32">
  <path class="green "d="M16 32c8.837 0 16-7.160 16-16s-7.163-16-16-16-16 7.163-16 16 7.163 16 16 16z"></path>
  <path class="red "d="M16 3c7.18 0 13 5.82 13 13s-5.82 13-13 13-13-5.82-13-13 5.82-13 13-13zM8 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM20 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM22.003 19.602l2.573 1.544c-1.749 2.908-4.935 4.855-8.576 4.855s-6.827-1.946-8.576-4.855l2.573-1.544c1.224 2.036 3.454 3.398 6.003 3.398s4.779-1.362 6.003-3.398z"></path>
    <path class="features" d="M8 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM20 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM22.003 19.602l2.573 1.544c-1.749 2.908-4.935 4.855-8.576 4.855s-6.827-1.946-8.576-4.855l2.573-1.544c1.224 2.036 3.454 3.398 6.003 3.398s4.779-1.362 6.003-3.398z 

                              M20 10c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2s2 0.895 2 2c0 1.105-0.895 2-2 2s-2-0.895-2-2zM22.003 19.602l2.573 1.544c-1.749 2.908-4.935 4.855-8.576 4.855s-6.827-1.946-8.576-4.855l2.573-1.544c1.224 2.036 3.454 3.398 6.003 3.398s4.779-1.362 6.003-3.398z 

                                 M22.003 19.602l2.573 1.544c-1.749 2.908-4.935 4.855-8.576 4.855s-6.827-1.946-8.576-4.855l2.573-1.544c1.224 2.036 3.454 3.398 6.003 3.398s4.779-1.362 6.003-3.398z"></path>
</svg>
```

The "features" (eyes/smile) can be separate paths or just one (I've provided) examples of both.

The trick here is to add the correct `viewbox` so that the SVG fills the whole SVG canvas. Then the SVG can be sized with CSS not HTML.

Comment: This is Perfect Idea, But can you also teach me how can i change mouth shapes ?